# How to paginate a list of content using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: jquery, button, pagination

I have a page where i have 100 videos in one single page.

How can i make my page show only 20 of those and rest of the content in cycle using *Next* and *Previous* button using jquery or JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can load it into an array and display the next 20. Have a pointer variable to keep track where you are.